# Call another function within a function and pass data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

To avoid duplicating code, I'd like to create the doMore() function in my controller.

doSomething() and doSomethingElse() would do stuff and then call doMore(), and each would then return to a different view.

Is this how I should do it?

```
class SomeController extends BaseController
{
    function doSomething()
    {
        // Do stuff here                

        return $this->doMore();

        return view('view1.index')->with(['data1' => $data1]->with(['data2' => $data2])
    }


    function doSomethingelse()
    {
        // Do stuff here        

        return $this->doMore();

        return view('view2.index')->with(['data1' => $data1]->with(['data2' => $data2])
    }


    function doMore()
    {
        // Do more stuff here

        return response(with(['data1' => $data1]->with(['data2' => $data2]))
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its done like this

```
 $result = $this->domore($something); 
return view('view1.index')->with('result' , $result)->with('test' , $test);
```

you will pass something to the function domore ane results will be saved in $result then you return what you want! you cant have 2 returns

but you will have to inject it if the function is in another class

Comment: Thanks, that work for returning multiple values? Is this: `return response(with(['data1' => $data1]->with(['data2' => $data2]))` the way to return multiple values?